# Getting CommitFailedError in python kafka consumer

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have created Kafka consumer in python with below configurations.

```
 consumer = KafkaConsumer(topic, 
                          group_id='consumer', 
                          bootstrap_servers=[bootstrap_servers], 
                          auto_offset_reset='latest', 
                          value_deserializer=lambda m:json.loads(m.decode('utf-8')), 
                          max_poll_records=1, 
                          max_poll_interval_ms=900000)
```

Processing time for each record is around 10 mins which is less than **max_poll_interval_ms** (15 mins) .Even after higher **max_poll_interval_ms** value, whenever consumer.commit() is called, I am getting below exception

```
kafka.errors.CommitFailedError: CommitFailedError: Commit cannot be completed since the group has already
            rebalanced and assigned the partitions to another member.
            This means that the time between subsequent calls to poll()
            was longer than the configured max_poll_interval_ms, which
            typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much
            time message processing. You can address this either by
            increasing the rebalance timeout with max_poll_interval_ms,
            or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll()
            with max_poll_records
```

I am not able to figure out why its failing, can anyone please help here?

Comment: What exactly does the code do that takes ten or more minutes per record? Are you calling `time.sleep` for example? Could you instead poll the records, add into some in memory list and process in another queue, not blocking the consumer?

Comment: Have you look into setting session.timeout.ms, more info [here](https://docs.confluent.io/3.0.0/clients/consumer.html)
And i agree processing the data in separate thread(if possible). 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37527439/kafka-consumer-group-is-rebalancing (see if this help)

Comment: In my case it does ML processing which takes more time, but as per my understanding setting  max_poll_interval_ms more than processing time should work. session.timeout.ms is set to default value. How does session.timeout.ms plays role here?

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm at what point in time you are commiting your offset? Are you using any one of the Commit APIs (Sync/Async) or you are just setting the auto commit properties such as enable.auto.commit = true auto.commit.interval.ms. Because, these parameters are the key ones which makes a consumer commit successful or failure. Also, it is good to understand the behaviour of the session.timeout.ms and the solution to your problem lies here.

### session.timeout.ms

The amount of time a consumer can be out of contact with the brokers while still
considered alive defaults to 3 seconds. If more than session.timeout.ms passes
without the consumer sending a heartbeat to the group coordinator, it is considered
dead and the group coordinator will trigger a rebalance of the consumer group to
allocate partitions from the dead consumer to the other consumers in the group. This
property is closely related to heartbeat.interval.ms. heartbeat.interval.ms con‐
trols how frequently the KafkaConsumer poll() method will send a heartbeat to the
group coordinator, whereas session.timeout.ms controls how long a consumer can
go without sending a heartbeat. Therefore, those two properties are typically modi‐
fied together—heatbeat.interval.ms must be lower than session.timeout.ms, and
is usually set to one-third of the timeout value. So if session.timeout.ms is 3 sec‐
onds, heartbeat.interval.ms should be 1 second. Setting session.timeout.ms
lower than the default will allow consumer groups to detect and recover from failure
sooner, but may also cause unwanted rebalances as a result of consumers taking
longer to complete the poll loop or garbage collection. Setting session.timeout.ms
higher will reduce the chance of accidental rebalance, but also means it will take
longer to detect a real failure.

Comment: As soon as processing is done i call consumer.commit() which is I guess sync commit. enable.auto.commit is set to false with default session.timeout.ms which is 30 sec

Comment: 30 Sec is way too low, as your single message processing time is up to 10 mins.  Can you try with following settings 

max_poll_records: 1
poll_timeout_ms: 6000
session_timeout_ms: 300000
maxPollInterval_minutes: 20

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I will try this setting. However I am still confused, how session timeout is related with processing time? Again as a understood max_poll_interval_ms is relay  on time taken by processing thread (processing time) and  session_timeout_ms is related to heartbeat  thread which keeps sending heart beats to the broker in background. Also what is poll_timeout_ms here. I did not find this config for consumer